# ibeaconの信号をAndroidで認識し、処理を書きたいが、UUID、mahorなどの指定の仕方がイマイチ分からない

Tags: android, ibeacon

お世話になっております。ibeaconの信号をAndroidで認識し、その信号に応じてアプリを画面遷移させる。という処理をしたいと考えております。 
しかし、自分の力不足が大きいのですが、調べていてイマイチ記述方法がわかりません。

UUID、major、minorをそれぞれ指定した場合

例えば 
UUIDがAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBCCCCCC
majorが01
minorが01
で、UIIDと、majorと、minorを指定し、その信号を受信した時に画面遷移するような事をしたいと考えております。

LeScanCallbackに、処理を記述するのかと思いますが、どのように記述するものなのでしょうか。 
beaconの認識、UUID、major、minorは認識できております。 
大変申し訳ないのですが、皆さんのお知恵をお借りできないでしょうか？ 
よろしくお願いいたします。

> private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback = new
>   BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() { @Override public void
>   onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi,byte[] scanRecord) {
>
> } };

Answer (score 1):

```
if(uuid.equals("指定したいUUID") && major.equals("指定したいmajor") && minor.equals("指定したいminor"))) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TestActivity.class);
  startActivity(intent);
};
```

上記で解決しました。